# Installation problem

Tags: ubuntu

what is the command to install 'xidel' on ubuntu? 
I tried **sudo apt -get install xidel** but I am getting an error 'Unable to locate package xidel'

Comment: This has been asked before - http://askubuntu.com/questions/378558/unable-to-locate-package-while-trying-to-install-packages-by-apt

Answer (score 3):

`xidel` is not in the official Ubuntu repositories (checked with `apt-cache search xidel` ).

Download appropriate package from their site http://www.videlibri.de/xidel.html#downloads, uncompress , and install.  Best would be the `*.deb` package, which you can simply install with `sudo dpkg -i /path/to/file.deb`. Check if it asks for dependencies - you may need to install those first. Refer to this question https://askubuntu.com/q/80655/295286